# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;

Tags: android, facebook

I know that Multidex problems is common here on StackOverflow, but none of the solutions worked for me.
I suspect that its bolts-android creating a conflict when compiling the facebook sdk since support:appcompatv7 also come with bolts if im not completely wrong. I have tried to exclude android-bolts with no luck. Also tried to use different versions of facebook-android-sdk, but didnt help much.

gradle(app):

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0') {
    exclude module: 'bolts-android'
}
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0+'
```

Comment: You could try to include the facebook sdk in your main project tree (rather than reference it in gradle) and delete the bolts part (or exclude it)? I had these kind of problems in the past with appcompat libs and remember it helped.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it didnt help actually..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem last week when i update the fb sdk but my conflict problems was between fresco and fb, i resolved excluding like this:

```
compile ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'){
      exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-android'
 }
```

Try to run dependencies and see which lib is causing this problem

You should run the following command in the terminal of android studio in order to check that:

```
  ./gradlew app:dependencies
```